# flask-restplus fields.Nested() with raw Dict (not model)

Tags: python, flask, model, flask-restplus

Spoiler alert: I posted my solution as an answer to this question

I am using [flastk-resptlus](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to create an API. I have to provide the data in a specific structure, which I have problems to get, see an example below:

What I need to get is this structure:

```py
{
    "metadata": {
        "files": [] 
    },
    "result" : {
        "data": [
                {
                 "user_id": 1,
                  "user_name": "user_1",
                  "user_role": "editor"
                },
                {
                  "user_id": 2
                  "user_name": "user_2",
                  "user_role": "editor"
                },
                {
                  "user_id": 3,
                  "user_name": "user_3",
                  "user_role": "curator"
                }
            ]
    }
}
```

But the problem comes that I cannot manage to get the structure of `"result" : { "data": []}` without making "data" a model itself.

What I tried to do so far (and did not work)

```py
# define metadata model
metadata_model = api.model('MetadataModel', {
          "files": fields.List(fields.String(required=False, description='')),
}
# define user model 
user_model = api.model('UserModel', {
          "user_id": fields.Integer(required=True, description=''),
          "user_name": fields.String(required=True, description=''),
          "user_role": fields.String(required=False, description='')
}

# here is where I have the problems
user_list_response =  api.model('ListUserResponse', {
            'metadata': fields.Nested(metadata_model),
            'result' :  {"data" : fields.List(fields.Nested(user_model))}
             })
```

Complains that cannot get the "schema" from `"data"` (because is not a defined model), but I don't want to be a new api model, just want to append a key called "data". Any suggestions?

This I tried and works, but is not what I want (because I miss the "data"):

```py
user_list_response =  api.model('ListUserResponse', {
            'metadata': fields.Nested(metadata_model),
            'result' :  fields.List(fields.Nested(user_model))
            })
```

I don't want `data` to be a model because the common structure of the api is the following:

```py
{
    "metadata": {
        "files": [] 
    },
    "result" : {
        "data": [
                <list of objects> # here must be listed the single model
            ]
    }
}
```

Then, `<list of objects>` can be users, addresses, jobs, whatever.. so I want to make a "general structure" in which then I can just inject the particular models (UserModel, AddressModel, JobModel, etc) without creating a special `data` model for each one.

Comment: I do not get your question fully. Can you provide a minimal running  example?

Comment: @Mol1narius I have rephrased the question and added example

Comment: I cannot understand the reason why you do not want to add another model? Can you comment on that?

The design of the `flask_Restplus` library does not support adding a key as you did. I suggest adding a fourth model. It only requires few lines of code and allows you to add further attributes on the level of the data_model.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't want a model for data, because the content of data changes (it can be users as the example, but it will be used to display addresses and any listed result), so If I implement a fourth model with data then I need to create a data model for each result, kind of : userDataList, AdressDataList, and so on.. and having so many different models for just a common "key" which is "data" makes my documentation of models too big for such a simple case, common for all cases where elements are listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My workaround solution that solves all my problems:

I create a new List fields class (it is mainly copied from fields.List), and then I just tune the output format and the schema in order to get the 'data' as key:

```py
class ListData(fields.Raw):
    '''
    Field for marshalling lists of other fields.

    See :ref:`list-field` for more information.

    :param cls_or_instance: The field type the list will contain.

    This is a modified version of fields.List Class in order to get 'data' as key envelope
    '''
    def __init__(self, cls_or_instance, **kwargs):
        self.min_items = kwargs.pop('min_items', None)
        self.max_items = kwargs.pop('max_items', None)
        self.unique = kwargs.pop('unique', None)
        super(ListData, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        error_msg = 'The type of the list elements must be a subclass of fields.Raw'
        if isinstance(cls_or_instance, type):
            if not issubclass(cls_or_instance, fields.Raw):
                raise MarshallingError(error_msg)
            self.container = cls_or_instance()
        else:
            if not isinstance(cls_or_instance, fields.Raw):
                raise MarshallingError(error_msg)
            self.container = cls_or_instance
    def format(self, value):

        if isinstance(value, set):
            value = list(value)

        is_nested = isinstance(self.container, fields.Nested) or type(self.container) is fields.Raw

        def is_attr(val):
            return self.container.attribute and hasattr(val, self.container.attribute)

        # Put 'data' as key before the list, and return the dict
        return {'data': [
            self.container.output(idx,
                val if (isinstance(val, dict) or is_attr(val)) and not is_nested else value)
            for idx, val in enumerate(value)
        ]}

    def output(self, key, data, ordered=False, **kwargs):
        value = fields.get_value(key if self.attribute is None else self.attribute, data)
        if fields.is_indexable_but_not_string(value) and not isinstance(value, dict):
            return self.format(value)

        if value is None:
            return self._v('default')
        return [marshal(value, self.container.nested)]

    def schema(self):
        schema = super(ListData, self).schema()
        schema.update(minItems=self._v('min_items'),
                      maxItems=self._v('max_items'),
                      uniqueItems=self._v('unique'))

        # work around to get the documentation as I want
        schema['type'] = 'object'
        schema['properties'] = {}
        schema['properties']['data'] = {}
        schema['properties']['data']['type'] = 'array'
        schema['properties']['data']['items'] = self.container.__schema__

        return schema
```

Answer (score 6):

A possible approach is to use `fields.Raw` which returns whatever serializable object you pass. Then, you can define a second function, which creates your result and uses `marshal`. `marshal` transforms your data according to a model and accepts an additional parameter called `envelope`. `envelope` surrounds your modeled data by a given key and does the trick.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, fields, Resource, marshal

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api()
api.init_app(app)

metadata_model = api.model("metadata", {
    'file': fields.String()
})

user_model = api.model('UserModel', {
          "user_id": fields.Integer(required=True, description=''),
          "user_name": fields.String(required=True, description=''),
          "user_role": fields.String(required=False, description='')
})

response_model = api.model("Result", {
    'metadata': fields.List(fields.Nested(metadata_model)),
    'result': fields.Raw()
})


@api.route("/test")
class ApiView(Resource):

    @api.marshal_with(response_model)
    def get(self):

        data = {'metadata': {},
                'result': self.get_user()}
        return data


    def get_user(self):
        # Access database and get data
        user_data = [{'user_id': 1, 'user_name': 'John', 'user_role': 'editor'},
                     {'user_id': 2, 'user_name': 'Sue', 'user_role': 'curator'}]

        # The kwarg envelope does the trick
        return marshal(user_data, user_model, envelope='data')


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

[image: Response]

Comment: Problem with this is that I loose the auto documentation part of because of the manual marshal() and the Raw() set.